# Traverse multi dimensional array recursively without using foreach

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this and the code using foreach loop.

```
$arr = array( array ( array( 'CAR_TIR', 'Tires', 100 ),
           array( 'CAR_OIL', 'Oil', 10 ),
           array( 'CAR_SPK', 'Spark Plugs', 4 )
          ),
       array ( array( 'VAN_TIR', 'Tires', 120 ),
           array( 'VAN_OIL', 'Oil', 12 ),
           array( 'VAN_SPK', 'Spark Plugs', 5 )
          ),
       array ( array( 'TRK_TIR', 'Tires', 150 ),
           array( 'TRK_OIL', 'Oil', 15 ),
           array( 'TRK_SPK', 'Spark Plugs', 6 )
          )
      );


function recarray($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            RecArray($value);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "key = $key value = $value";
       }
    }
}
recarray($arr);
```

I have to traverse the array using recursion and without using foreach.

Comment: `without using foreach` - why? `foreach` is kind and a gentle lover... This smells of homework to me, if it is please tag it as such.

Comment: yeah its kind a home work. Thanks alot

Comment: Also, traversing arrays with foreach is not resource-efficient when you don't really need to get all values from each position of the array, or you just want to delete items from the child array.

Answer (score 7):

Simple depth first search:

```
function DFS($array) {      
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i ++) {
        if (is_array($array[$i])) {
            DFS($array[$i]);
        }
        else {
            echo "key: ".$i.", value: ".$array[$i]."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)... means that the count() function will be fired for EVERY iteration of $array.
Better to do this: 
    $arrayCount = count($array); 
    for($i = 0; $i < $arrayCount; $i++)...

Answer (score 2):

What about [array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)? it can apply function to each element of the array:

```
function test_print($value, $key)
{
    echo "key = $key value = $value";
}

array_walk_recursive($arr, 'test_print');
```

**not tested**

Answer (score 0):

I would use a while loop - like

```
while($i < count($array)) {}
```

Comment: there's no `.length` property in php