# JQuery loop though multidimensional json array using for loop

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through JSON data

```
{"reply":[{"ticketnumber":"61947"}],"all":[{"ticketnumber":"61947"}]);
```

using

```
success: function(data) {
    for(var i in data) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
}
```

but i cannot get the key values, so i want to get "reply" and "all" then loop through those inside the first loop

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: " i want to get "reply" and "all" then loop through those inside the first loop"

Comment: so a recursive loop?

Comment: Not getting what you mean.

Comment: well the json data returns data inside both "reply" and "all", but i want to display those values (reply and all) then loop the data inside "reply" and "all"

Comment: @palaѕн i guess he wants a multi dimension traverser loop

Comment: this should help you get on the right track https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538576/traverse-multi-dimensional-array-recursively-without-using-foreach

Comment: @ImmortalDude that's PHP

Comment: loops are essentially the same for all languages with just language specific syntactical differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then loop the data inside "reply" and "all" using `for..of` like:

```js
const data = {
  "reply": [{
    "ticketnumber": "61947"
  }],
  "all": [{
    "ticketnumber": "61947"
  }]
};

for (var key of Object.keys(data)) {
  console.log(key);
  for (var i of data[key]) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```